# IAM Policy Condition - more examples

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created an IAM Policy & condition (CEL). Within a condition, is it possible to refer to specific Permission within a Role and effectively 'disable' the Permission. I would like to use the provided IAM Pre-Defined Roles with exception(s) for given permission. Could you provide some further, more extensive examples?

My specific example using Condition 'disable' one Permission:

- Role (pre-defined): 'roles/resourcemanager.folderAdmin'
- Permission (disable): 'resourcemanager.projects.move'

Answer (score 1):

Today, permission can be only added. The final set of permission is the addition of the permission at

- The ressource level (for example, the compute engine)
- The project level
- The folder(s) level(s)
- The organisation level

That's why it's important to grant only the minimal permission at the higher level of the hierarchy (organisation level), because the permissions come only in addition and you can't remove them..... today.

*The Deny policy is under progress, no timeline yet. But stay tuned, it could be a Xmas present!*

The condition, can't change this behavior. You can do something like this with permission

- Without any condition, create a custom role with the required permission and grant it on the resource
- On a certain condition, grant also the predefined role (with the additional permission)